# RegEx to split address into three distinct Series [Part 1]

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm experimenting/learning Python with a data set containing customers information.

The DataFrame structure is the following (these are made up records):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_name' : ['James', 'Mary', 'David', 'Linda', 'George', 'Jennifer', 'John', 'Maria', 'Charles', 'Helen'],
                   'address' : ['Main St 59', 'Yellow Av 11 b.F1', 'Terrazzo Way 100-102', np.nan, 'Hamilton St 159 b.A/B', np.nan, 'Henry St 7 D', 'Mc-Kenzie Av 40P b.1', 'Neptune Av 14 15 b.G', np.nan ], 
                   'postal_code' : [1410, 1210, 1020, np.nan, 1310, np.nan, 1080, 1190, 1040, np.nan], 
                  })

print(df)

   cus_name                address  postal_code
0     James             Main St 59       1410.0
1      Mary      Yellow Av 11 b.F1       1210.0
2     David   Terrazzo Way 100-102       1020.0
3     Linda                    NaN          NaN
4    George  Hamilton St 159 b.A/B       1310.0
5  Jennifer                    NaN          NaN
6      John           Henry St 7 D       1080.0
7     Maria   Mc-Kenzie Av 40P b.1       1190.0
8   Charles   Neptune Av 14 15 b.G       1040.0
9     Helen                    NaN          NaN
```

I'm particularly interested in the `address` Series. Specifically, my goal is to "split" the information of the **street**, **number**, and **box** into three distinct Series.

For instance, after the transformation, the first and seventh record/row should look like this:

```
| cus_name | street       | number | box | postal_code |
|----------|--------------|--------|-----|-------------|
| James    | Main St      | 59     | NaN | 1410        |
| Maria    | Mc-Kenzie Av | 40P    | 1   | 1190.0      |
```

At first, I had no idea how to tackle this problem. After doing some research here, I found some interesting related posts that use regular expressions.

Since I'm no expert in Python (nor regular expressions), I thought I could start by identifying the pattern in the `address` Series. In fact, each address has the following pattern:

- The **street** part which is located at the beginning of the string. It is composed of one or more words separated by a white-space character or a dash (e.g. `Mc-Kenzie Av`);
- The **number** part which is located in the middle of the string. It is composed of one or more alpha-numeric words separated by a white-space character or a dash (e.g. `100-102`, `7 D`);
- The **box** part which is located at the end of the string. It always immediately follows the `b.`characters and is composed of one word containing alpha-numeric characters and possibly some special characters (e.g. `A/B`, `F1`).

I'm asking for help to achieve my desired goal using regular expressions (if regex is the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another regex approach:

```
In [913]: df[['street', 'number', 'box']] = df.address.str.extract(r'(\D+)\s+(\d+[\s-]?(?!b)\w*)(?:\s+b\.)?(\S+)?', expand=True)

In [914]: df
Out[914]: 
   cus_name                address  postal_code        street   number  box
0     James             Main St 59       1410.0       Main St       59  NaN
1      Mary      Yellow Av 11 b.F1       1210.0     Yellow Av       11   F1
2     David   Terrazzo Way 100-102       1020.0  Terrazzo Way  100-102  NaN
3     Linda                    NaN          NaN           NaN      NaN  NaN
4    George  Hamilton St 159 b.A/B       1310.0   Hamilton St      159  A/B
5  Jennifer                    NaN          NaN           NaN      NaN  NaN
6      John           Henry St 7 D       1080.0      Henry St      7 D  NaN
7     Maria   Mc-Kenzie Av 40P b.1       1190.0  Mc-Kenzie Av      40P    1
8   Charles   Neptune Av 14 15 b.G       1040.0    Neptune Av    14 15    G
9     Helen                    NaN          NaN           NaN      NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
pattern = "^(?P<street>.+)\s+(?P<number>[\d\w]+)\s+b\.(?P<box>.*)$"
df['address'].str.extract(pattern)
```

output

```
          street number  box
0            NaN    NaN  NaN
1      Yellow Av     11   F1
2            NaN    NaN  NaN
3            NaN    NaN  NaN
4    Hamilton St    159  A/B
5            NaN    NaN  NaN
6            NaN    NaN  NaN
7   Mc-Kenzie Av    40P    1
8  Neptune Av 14     15    G
9            NaN    NaN  NaN
```

For an explanation, paste the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/).

If you require the street be strictly without numbers, e.g. line 8 above, use this pattern:

```
pattern = "^(?P<street>[\D]+)\s+(?P<number>[\w\s]+)\s+b\.(?P<box>.*)$"
```

which gives:

```
         street number  box
0           NaN    NaN  NaN
1     Yellow Av     11   F1
2           NaN    NaN  NaN
3           NaN    NaN  NaN
4   Hamilton St    159  A/B
5           NaN    NaN  NaN
6           NaN    NaN  NaN
7  Mc-Kenzie Av    40P    1
8    Neptune Av  14 15    G
9           NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: `[\d\w]` = `\w`, and `b.` must be `b\.` as `.` is a dot in the original data.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, much appreciated. Your solution is almost what I was looking for. Is there a simple way to modify your code so that when the box information is missing, the pattern still captures the street and number parts? I added an explicit example to my original post.

Comment: Similar to the other answer, you can change the pattern to `pattern = "^(?P<street>.+)\s+(?P<number>[\w-]+)?[\s+b\.]?(?P<box>.*)$"`.