# RegEx to split address into three distinct Series [Part 2]

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

This is the continuation of my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57292844/regex-to-split-address-into-three-distinct-series) on using regular expressions to split a pandas Series containing addresses into three disctint fields (the **street**, **the number**, and the **box**).

My initial example was the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_name' : ['James', 'Mary', 'David', 'Linda', 'George', 'Jennifer', 'John', 'Maria', 'Charles', 'Helen'],
                   'address' : ['Main St 59', 'Yellow Av 11 b.F1', 'Terrazzo Way 100-102', np.nan, 'Hamilton St 159 b.A/B', np.nan, 'Henry St 7 D', 'Mc-Kenzie Av 40P b.1', 'Neptune Av 14 15 b.G', np.nan ], 
                   'postal_code' : [1410, 1210, 1020, np.nan, 1310, np.nan, 1080, 1190, 1040, np.nan], 
                  })

print(df)

   cus_name                address  postal_code
0     James             Main St 59       1410.0
1      Mary      Yellow Av 11 b.F1       1210.0
2     David   Terrazzo Way 100-102       1020.0
3     Linda                    NaN          NaN
4    George  Hamilton St 159 b.A/B       1310.0
5  Jennifer                    NaN          NaN
6      John           Henry St 7 D       1080.0
7     Maria   Mc-Kenzie Av 40P b.1       1190.0
8   Charles   Neptune Av 14 15 b.G       1040.0
9     Helen                    NaN          NaN
```

Using the regex pattern from the solution given by **RomanPerekhrest**, the `address` Series nicely splits into the 3 desired fields.

```py
pattern = pattern ='(\D+)\s+(\d+[\s-]?(?!b)\w*)(?:\s+b\.)?(\S+)?'
print(df['address'].str.extract(pattern, expand = True))

              0        1    2
0       Main St       59  NaN
1     Yellow Av       11   F1
2  Terrazzo Way  100-102  NaN
3           NaN      NaN  NaN
4   Hamilton St      159  A/B
5           NaN      NaN  NaN
6      Henry St      7 D  NaN
7  Mc-Kenzie Av      40P    1
8    Neptune Av    14 15    G
9           NaN      NaN  NaN
```

Unfortunately, in my previous post, I didn't account for the case where the address only contains the street information (e.g. `Place de la Monnaie`).

In this case, the above regex pattern don't work anymore. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/QSSx8J/2) regex101 link.

I tried to modify the regex pattern for half-an-hour to account for this case without any success. What I noticed is that even though the **number** field can have word characters, it always starts with a digit when non-missing.

Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just make the number optional as well? See https://regex101.com/r/cz2E9w/1

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to simplify this regex, but this should work: `\D+$|(\D+)\s+(\d+[\s-]?(?!b)\w*)(?:\s+b\.)?(\S+)?`

Answer (score 1):

this pattern can help:

```
(\D+)\s((\d+[\s-]?(?!b)\w*)(?:\s+b\.)?(\S+)?)*
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when the **number** and **box** information are missing. Sere [here](https://regex101.com/r/cz2E9w/2).